# Are there characteristic-dependent Betti numbers in characteristic not equal to two?

Tags: homological-algebra, characteristic-p, simplicial-complexes, monomial-ideals

Let $\Delta$ be a finite simplicial complex on $n$ vertices. Let $S = \mathbb{k}[\mathbf{x}]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $\mathbb{k}$ in $n$ variables and $I$ be the Stanley-Reisner ideal of $\Delta$ in $S$. It is well-known that the Betti numbers (graded or otherwise) appearing in the free resolution of $I$ may depend on the ground field $\mathbb{k}$. A classic example of this is the minimal triangulation of the real projective plane with Stanley-Reisner ideal
$$I = \langle abc, abe, acf, ade, adf, bcd, bdf, bef, cde, cef \rangle.$$
When the characteristic of $\mathbb{k}$ is $2$ then the projective dimension of $I$ (as an $S$-module) is 3 while in all other cases it is 2. This example and others can be found in Dalili and Kummini's paper [Dependence Of Betti Numbers On Characteristic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4243.pdf) and the references there.

In all of the examples I've seen of complexes whose Betti numbers are characteristic-dependent, the offending characteristic has always been 2, and only 2. That is, the Betti numbers are stable in all cases except when the characteristic of $\mathbb{k}$ is 2. My intuition tells me there must be ideals with other offending characteristics. As I have no idea how to construct one and my computer experiments (using [RandomIdeals](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/RandomIdeals/html/index.html)) have come up empty my questions are the following.

**Question** 1: Are there known examples of square-free monomial ideals with characteristic-dependent Betti numbers for characteristics other than two?

**Question** 2: Is there one whose only offending characteristic is 3?

Comment: According to the paper you linked, the dependence on the characteristic in your example seems to be related to the torsion in the homology group $H_1(\mathbb{PR}_2,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. My guess would thus be that Betti numbers differ in characteristic 3 for a simplicial complex having $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as its first homology group. Have you already tried this?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle I don't know how to construct such a thing so I'm looking into Moore spaces and the like. If you have an example at hand I'm happy to run the calculation to see if it's characteristic dependent.

Comment: I looked at Lutz' 12 vertex triangulation of the lens space L(3,1). Neither the Stanley-Reisner ideal nor the facet ideal of this complex has the desired property.

Comment: For a 2 dimensional example, you might try yo look at the presentation complex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex) of the presentation $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}=\langle x | x^3=1 \rangle$. It has a triangulation with 9 vertices and facets $abd,acd,abf,acf,abe,ace,def,bcg,ceg,deg,bdg,bch,cfh,efh,beh,bci,cdi,dfi,bfi$.

Comment: That works! The projective dimension of the Stanley-Reisner ideal of that complex is 6 in characteristic 3 and is 5 in other characteristics. If you want to post it as an answer I'd happily accept it (and add the Betti tables if necessary). Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to tag you in the last comment, @AntoineLabelle. Let me know if you will/won't post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I posted it, you can add the Betti tables if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the presentation complex of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}=\langle x|x^3=1 \rangle$, consisting of a full triangle with all three edges identified in the same orientation. It has a triangulation with 9 vertices and facets $abd,acd,abf,acf,abe,ace,def,bcg,ceg,deg,bdg,bch,cfh,efh,beh,bci,cdi,dfi,bfi$.

The projective dimension of the corresponding Stanley-Reisner ideal is 6 in characteristic 3 and 5 in all others characteristics, which answers question 2 positively.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: There is a 3-dimensional simplicial complex $\Delta$ with $f$-vector $(1, 9, 36, 84, 42)$ whose Stanley-Reisner ideal has characteristic-dependent Betti numbers. Here is some [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/) code to construct such an example.

```
-- set up some polynomial rings
X = vars(0..8);
char2 = ZZ/2[X];
char3 = ZZ/3[X];
char5 = ZZ/5[X];
char0 = QQ[X];

-- the square-free ideal
I = ideal "abcd,abce,abde,acde,bcde,abcf,abdf,acdf,bcdf,abef,acef,bcef,abcg,abdg,bcdg,aceg,bceg,adeg,bdeg,cdeg,bcfg,cdfg,befg,defg,abch,abdh,acdh,aceh,cdeh,acfh,bcfh,adfh,bdfh,cdfh,aefh,defh,abgh,acgh,bcgh,adgh,bdgh,cdgh,aegh,degh,bfgh,dfgh,efgh,abci,abdi,abei,acei,bdei,abfi,bcfi,adfi,aefi,befi,cefi,defi,abgi,acgi,bcgi,adgi,aegi,begi,cegi,degi,cfgi,dfgi,efgi,abhi,achi,bchi,bdhi,cehi,dehi,afhi,bfhi,cfhi,dfhi,efhi,dghi,eghi,fghi"

-- make the betti computations
betti res module sub(I, char0)
betti res module sub(I, char2)
betti res module sub(I, char3)
betti res module sub(I, char5)
```

<s>This settles Question 1 but doesn't quite answer Question 2 because I don't have a proof that the only offending characteristic is 3 but it's a start in that direction.</s>

**Edit**: Using the [SimplicialComplexes](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/SimplicialComplexes/html/) package in Macaulay2 one can show that $\Delta$ has one non-trivial homology group over $\mathbb{Z}$: $\tilde{H}_2(\Delta; \mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z}^{14}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. So by Remark 2.2 in [the paper cited in the OP](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4243.pdf) its Betti numbers are only characteristic dependent when the characteristic is three.

The ideal $I$, like Reisner's example in the OP, has a linear resolution in most characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to either of your questions, but I don’t have enough reputation to comment.  Perhaps the recent preprint of Booms, Erman and Yang might be of interest to you: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.13914.pdf

The title references Veronese syzygies (Edit: looks like the title changed in a recent update and no longer references Veronese syzygies), but the heuristic developed is based on syzygies of random Stanley-Reisner ideals.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great reference.